# Out of memory Exception while dealing with images. in java

Tags: java, imgscalr

==================Hi here is the mycode ==============================

this is example to

> imgscalr

```
package anil1.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageFilter;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

import static org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

public class ImageScalar {
    public static void thum(String img) throws Exception
    {

         String path1 = "."; 

          String files;
          File folder = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\Myapp\\images\\candidates");
          File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
          {

           if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
           {
           files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
               if (files.endsWith(".jpg") || files.endsWith(".png") || files.endsWith(".jpeg")|| files.endsWith(".JPEG") )
               {

            boolean token =false;
        String path=listOfFiles[i].getPath();

        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));


    //  BufferedImage thumbnail =Scalr.crop(originalImage, 140, 140, 140, 140);

        BufferedImage thumbnail=Scalr.resize(originalImage, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY,Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, 180, 250);




        String parent = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\Myapp";
        String child = "\\Thumbs\\images\\candidates";



    String  total=parent+child+path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\"));
    String  total1=parent+child;
    System.out.println(total);

    File f=new File(total1);
    File f1=new File(path);
    File f2=new File(total);
    try{
        if(f1.exists()){
        if(f.exists())
        {

            System.out.println("from if");
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpeg", f2);

        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("from else");
            f.mkdirs();
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpeg", f2);

        }}
        if (new File(total1).exists())
        token=true;

        System.out.println(token);

               }finally{
                   originalImage.flush();  
                   thumbnail.flush();
                f=null;   
                f1=null;
                thumbnail=null;
                originalImage=null;
               }
             }//if
          }//for
    }//main

    }//class




public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    thum("");
}
}
```

after processing some images i got  following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.createOptimalImage(Scalr.java:2006)
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.scaleImage(Scalr.java:2133)
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.scaleImageIncrementally(Scalr.java:2275)
    at org.imgscalr.Scalr.resize(Scalr.java:1711)
    at anil1.main.ImageScalar.thum(ImageScalar.java:40)
    at anil1.main.ImageScalar.main(ImageScalar.java:114)
```

i am unable find out solution can any one help to me?

Comment: Imagines expand to their full uncompressed size when loaded.  This means an image can take up to 20-60x as much memory as it odes disk space.  I would increase your maximum memory size until this doesn't happen.

Comment: but i  nullify  everything what i created

Comment: That may not be enough.  Another cause of OOME is reading corrupt files.  Some libraries handle these better than others so the image can appear to fine but actually is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is hard to read, because it's not indented properly, but it seems you're processing one image at a time in memory, so if that causes an OutOfMemoryError, then you don't have much choice except increase the memory of your VM, or find a library that uses less memory to do the same thing.

To increase the heap memory, use the `-Xmx` flag to launch your program. For example, for a heap of 512 MBs, you would use

```
java -Xmx512m my.MainClass
```

Comment: what about i did it in webapplications

Comment: Same thing. Start your Tomcat or whatever container you're using with the above option.

Comment: hi jb that works but i got Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type but that image was readable and exists what was thw solution

Comment: Try to figure it out yourself using the stack trace of the exception, and if you can't, ask another question, containing the indented code causing the exception, and the full stack trace of the exception.